# Back to my application when call direction from google map in Android

Tags: android, maps, stack, task

I have an application get direction via google map. Example Activity A call google map:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myuri));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps","com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

It show 
Image 1: http://flic.kr/p/eBnRCy
then show
Image 2: http://flic.kr/p/eBjGWn

How to from image 2, I can back again my application(Activity A), don't back again image 1. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to hack it with `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`, which removes first `Activity` as soon as a second is opened. This will work if the two screens you put into question are two instances of `Activity` (even if they are the same class).

Comment: Maciej, Thanks this answer. I try: intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK). It's still, 2 screens come from google map application when I run code above my question. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @VanVo If this doesn't work, then it's outside of your control what other app does.

Comment: Thanks, I will try other solutions :)